# How to use -cd label in latexmkrc when "No file C1.aux LABELS NOT IMPORTED." error occured

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, standalone, ref, xr

I just get `No file C1.aux LABELS NOT IMPORTED.` error when I try to use `\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}` and `\externaldocument{C1}` commands, in order to quote from another latex files. I'm trying to use the standalone package because I get faster compile time when deal with individual tex files. And I read this from another problem which said there should be a latexmkrc file and using `-cd` commands, but the answer doesn't tell exactly how to write the latexmkrc file.

Comment: the choice to use latexmk or not is like the choice of which editor you use or which operating system, it affects details of what commands you run but isn't related to any tex error. if there is no `C1.aux` then presumably you haven't yet run latex on `C1.tex` so do that first then if you still get an error, show your tex code so someone has a chance to correct it.

Comment: but if you are including chapters via standalone they are essentially just input so they are part of the current document not external documents and you shouldn't need to use xr at all I would expect?

Comment: Hi David, I use both MiKTeX(offline) and Overleaf(online) and this error only shows on the overleaf. I have a `C1.axu` generated by the MiKTex and I can upload that file to overleaf.

Comment: I just using `xr` package to cross referencing, and that's when the error occured.

Comment: I know what xr does (I wrote it) but if you are including chapters then they may be separate source files but to latex they are part of the same document so just use normal `\label` and `\ref` not the `xr` mechanisms. But maybe you are not doing that (You have given very few clues about your source files) Overleaf will certainly need to see any aux files that you reference using `xr` so yes you need to copy them from a local run or from another overleaf project

Comment: Yeah, I only use `cref` in my code, and when I replace that to regular `\ref`, nothing changed. Also, when I remove the `xr` package, there where a bunch of error occurred. maybe it help, but I use `\externaldocument{C1}` commands to quote equations from another file, maybe that is the origin of the error?

Comment: externaldocument references the aux file but as I said in the original comment it is not clear that you should be using that or xr at all.  your question suggests  not but as you have posted no code impossible to say